# Missing Bootstrap Intellisense Options in .Net 6 - Blazor Page/Component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm new to Blazor Components and created a Blazor App using .Net 6 -  VS 2022.  It's my understanding that Bootstrap, or at least a subset of the CSS file, comes installed and is an intergral part of developing Blazor Pages/Components.  In every tutorial I've read/watched intellisense includes a list of "Bootstrap" Options vs. my options which displays the Field Icon.  I've included screens shots setting a Card Class... ASP.Net Core Online Course vs. my VS 2022 environment.

[Intellisense from Introducing ASP.Net Core Course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JeUn.png)

[My Intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrrTS.png)

It looks like the same options are available but any ideas why the Bootstrap Icons do not display?  Do I have something configured incorrectly? Am I referencing Bootstap CSS correctly and it's just an icon issue?  Also, why would a "lock" icon  be displaying... is the CSS file locked?

[_Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rawnc.png)

[Default CSS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLeOl.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Please post code as code - debugging images is a farce

Comment: Good to know my installation is not an anomolly.  In general I'm so impressed with how well intellisense works and VS error traps.   Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing bootstrap icon was a bug (regression) due to a change in how VS caches icons, which led to it being unable to locate the resource for that icon.  This issue was fixed, oh, sometime earlier today (or will be in 17.2 Preview 1).

The lock is an overlay that isn't expected to be applied to these icons, but with some of the editor architecture changes that have happened recently it's slipped in there.  It's also purely cosmetic.

(Source: am feature dev for CSS editor in VS)

If you do encounter any functional issues, please report them through the VS feedback system.  Most issues do get routed directly to the engineering teams pretty quickly.  Even cosmetic issues like "I'm confused, does the lock icon mean the file is locked?" are good feedback and can help us improve our UX (though they're often triaged as low priority and may sit for a while - but we really do want to fix them if we can).